# How to check if a container exists in cosmos DB using the node sdk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, azure-cosmosdb

I want to check if a container exists and if not, initialize it. I was hoping for something like the following:

```
const { endpoint, key, databaseId } = config;
const containerName = "container1"
const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint ,key});
const containerDefinition = getContainerDefinition(containerName);
const db = await createDatabase(client, databaseId);
if (!db.containers.contains(containerName)
{
 // Do something
}
```

The reason I'm not using "createIfNotExists" is because I would need to make a 2nd call to check if the container returned is populated with items or not. The container I'm creating is going to hold settings data which will be static once the container is initially created. This settings check is going to happen per request so I'd like to minimize the database calls and operations if possible.

I tried doing something like:

```
try
{
 db.container(containerName).read();
}
catch(err)
{
  if(err.message.contains("Resource Not Found"))
  {
    // do something
  }
}
```

But that doesn't seem like the right way to do it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why dont you do createIfNotExists on app start?

Comment: This is being deployed through azure functions. The containers won't be initialized until someone calls that specific function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite clear on why you would need to do this since typically you only need to do this sort of thing once for the life of your application instance. But I would not recommend doing it this way.

When you query Cosmos to test the existence of a database, container, etc., this hits the master partition for the account. The master partition is kind of like a tiny Cosmos database with all of your account meta data in it.

This master partition is allocated a small amount of the RU/s that manage the metadata operations. So if you app is designed to make these types of calls for every single request, it's quite likely you will get rate limited in your application.

If there is some way you can design this such that it doesn't have to query for the existence of a container then I would pursue that instead.

Comment: @MarkBrown...What's the recommendation from the Cosmos DB team on this? Should this be done as part of account creation process (through ARM template for resource creation+SDK for initial seed data)?

Comment: @MarkBrown, I'm currently using azure functions with cosmosDB and I'm having each function correspond to a container. When a function gets called it's calling createIfNotExists on the containers to create them if they're not in the database. Should this also not be used because createIfNotExistst would query the master partition too?

Comment: @GauravMantri, our recommendation is that when an app starts it goes and creates static references to any databases/containers objects and keeps them alive for the life of the application.

Comment: @avenmia, yes CreateIfNotExist hits master partition. It is fine to call in the startup for the Function. But I would not do this on every request. You should create static references for both CosmosClient and any Container references you need and keep them alive for the life of the application.

Comment: Thank you, that's a huge help! I'll do it that way.

Comment: @MarkBrown Is there support/documentation for creating static references in the startup of the function? I found several C# references, but I'm looking for node. It looks like I can't use top level awaits assuming I put the initialization code above the function.

Comment: Yep, take a look here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#static-clients

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. So i think you have few options

1. Just call `const { container } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists({ id: "Container" });` it will be fast probably few milliseconds, since I went via code at looks like it will always try to read from cosmos :( If you want to still check if container exists [sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/b585ceef62bd1eb4368252dc8b5161bd60808dfb/sdk/cosmosdb/cosmos/samples/ContainerManagement.ts) has methods(But again no real benefits ):

> const iterator = database.containers.readAll();

> const { resources: containersList } = await iterator.fetchAll();

2. Create singleton and first time just initialise all your containers so next time you dont call it, sure if you scale each instance will do the same
3. My favourite, use terraform/armtemplates/bicep to spin up infrastructure so you code wont need to handle that

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
async function check_container_exist(databaseId,containerId) {
    let exist = false;
    const querySpec = {
        query: "SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.id = @container",
        parameters: [
            {name: "@container", value: containerId}
        ]
    };
    const response = await client.database(databaseId).containers.query(querySpec).fetchNext();
    if(response.resources[0]){
        exist = true;
    }
    return exist;
}
```